# Can I change an index in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each, html5-audio

I have a series of `<div>`s each with an id of a color name e.g `<div id="white"></div>` that loads an audio file and fills a couple heading tags with the artist and track title gathered from an ajax call when the div is clicked

HTML

```
<audio id="song" preload="none">
</audio>
<div id="white"></div>
<div id="pink"></div>
<div id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('song').play()"></div>
<div>
  <h2 id="title"></h2>
  <h3 id="artist"></h3>
</div>`
```

Javascript

```
$("#white").click(function(){
    $("#song").attr('src',data[0].songSrc);
    $("h2").html(data[0].title)
    $("h3").html(data[0].artist)
}); 

$("#pink").click(function(){
    $("#song").attr('src',data[1].songSrc);
    $("h2").html(data[1].title)
    $("h3").html(data[1].artist)
});
```

Could I use a for loop or `$.each` rather than repeating the same code and manually changing the div id and item's index for each of the 19 items?

Here is my bin where I am working this out: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xahuxid/4/edit?html,js,output)

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('song').play()"></div>
```

Comment: I guess you are fundamentally doing it wrong! `:(`

Comment: @Praveen, could you be more specific?

Comment: That's what I am still trying to understand. `:(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you give all your colors a common class and then store the object index in a data attribute.  Then you can just have one click event which populates the correct data.  Something like this:

```js
$("div.color").click(function(){
  var index = $(this).data('src');
  $("#song").attr('src',data[index].songSrc);
  $("h2").html(data[index].title);
  $("h3").html(data[index].artist);
});
```

```html
<div id="white" class="color" data-src="0"></div>
<div id="pink" class="color" data-src="1"></div>
```

Comment: Got it thank you! I figured I would have to add a universal class, but was stuck on the rest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want but this should get you in the right direction.

Html

```
<div id="content">
  <audio id="song" preload="none"></audio>
</div>
<div class="songs"></div>
```

and then with Javascript/jQuery

```
var html = '';
//Create a div for each fetched song
$.each(data, function(index,item){
  html += '<div class="song" data-song-id="'+index+'" data-artist="'+item.artist+'" data-src="'+item.songSrc+'"></div>';
});
// and add them to the div element with the class songs
$('.songs').html(html);

//Listen to clicks on all divs with the class song
$('.songs').on('click', '.song' function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  var songId = $this.data('song-id');
  var artist = $this.data('artist');
  var src = $this.data('src');
  $("#song").attr('src',src);
})
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to increment the index used to access the `data` array. In your case you will always use the same item from that array.

Comment: The $.each function will iterate over the response data and increment index

Comment: @Andy I updated the code question, hopefully it helps clarify. I'm not sure exactly how to phrase what I am asking. Basically I want to use a loop (if possible), so I don't have to keep repeating the .click function for each the 19 divs on the page

Comment: The code above does that. You only have one event handler listening to click event on all the divs we add to the dom. As long as it has the class name song

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to refactor both, html and js. 
At HTML you have to replace the static div's, the ones that have an id. Instead of that, use a container where all songs will be appended.

At JS, create DOM elements for each song, and append it to the songs container. Before, be sure, that all elements has "click" event handler with songs specific data. Take advantage of 'bind'

**HTML**

```
  <div class="songs"></div>

  <div id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('song').play()"></div>
  <div>
    <h2 id="title"></h2>
    <h3 id="artist"></h3>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
myUrl='http://meyecare.herokuapp.com/api/v1/songs';
$(window).load(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url: myUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index,item){
        var element = $( "<div id='" + item.color + "'></p>" );
        element.on('click', function(){
          $("#song").attr('src',this.songSrc);
          $("h2").html(this.title);
          $("h3").html(this.artist);
        }.bind(item)); 
        element.appendTo(".songs");    
      }); 
    }, 
    error: function(){
      console.log('Shnope!');
    },
  });
});
```